# Prove that $\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & d \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & d \end{pmatrix}$ are similar iff $a \neq d$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, similar-matrices

> Prove that $\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & d \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & d \end{pmatrix}$ are similar iff $a \neq d$.

The problem with this is that most properties that I've tried i.e. rank, determinant are the same if $a=d$. Showing this algebraically gets really ugly so this is not a good idea.

Comment: If $a=d$, the first matrix is $a I_2$. What can you say of a matrix which is similar to $a I_2$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $t=\frac{b}{d-a}$. It's easy to check that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & t \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 \\
0 & d
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -t \\
0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
0 & d
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The converse follows from the fact that a scalar matrix commutes with any other matrix.